# VM Android on host Ubuntu: no sound

Tags: audio, linux, virtualbox

I'm using Android in a virtual machine while the host is Ubuntu 16.10.

I've followed this tutorial here: http://www.linux.org/threads/android-4-4-kitkat-in-virtualbox.7175/

and everything is working great. Except I can't get any sound.

My config:

- VirtualBox Version 5.1.6_Ubuntu r110634
- Guest: android-x86-4.4-RC2 (KitKat)
- Host: Ubuntu 16.10 64bits

Settings for the Virtual machine:

- settings > audio > Host: ALSA Audio Driver
- settings > audio > Audio Controller: SoundBlaster 16.

I've tried to use as settings in "Host":  *PulseAudio*, and in "Audio controller" *Intel HD Audio* or *ICH AC97*, but for the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by upgrading my config:

- VirtualBox Version 5.1.14 r112924 (Qt5.6.1)
- Android 6.0.1

with settings > audio:

- ALSA Audio driver
- ICH AC97